# Mcrypt PHP extension required. Laravel, Xampp error

Tags: 14.04, php, xampp, laravel

I'm having trouble with Ubuntu 14.04, Xampp and Laravel. I'm getting `Mcrypt PHP extension required. Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-install-cmd event returned with an error` when try to install laravel.

I know there are several thread on it and I tried most of them but no luck.

Comment: here you can check it for windows, linux, mac installations of mcrypt extension. http://www.kvcodes.com/2014/07/laravel-requires-mcrypt-php-extension/

Answer (score 10):

The desired `Mcrypt PHP extension` is packaged in a different package, namely `php5-mcrypt`. To get this package installed on your machine, you can use `apt-get`, like this:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt
```

In addition, PHP extensions have to be registered with the correct Server API (SAPI); there is a command-line tool called `php5enmod` provided by the packager to simplify this process; e.g.

```
sudo php5enmod mcrypt
```

will add the correct `extension=mcrypt.so` line to all the relevant `php.ini` files.

Comment: +1 But, as @Whaaaaaat commented, I'd like to understand things as newbie linux user

Comment: Thanks Everyone. If you already install PHPMyadmin you don't need to install mycrypt again. Make sure myscrypt is enabled. Just execute the following code:
`sudo php5enmod mcrypt`

Answer (score 1):

Enable the PHP mcrypt module before installing Laravel.

Using the command: `sudo php5enmod mcrypt`